# Change Package Name from two words to three words

Tags: android, android-studio

How to change a package from

anyword.someword

to

newword.anyword.someword   ?

So, adding a new word to the start of a two word package name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify your package name, you can use the **Refactor** feature of Android Studio.

Be careful, there are some things to pay attention. [See the developer guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id#change_the_package_name)